# Which language is the following program written in?

Tags: programming-languages, identify

http://www.geocities.com/CapeCanaveral/Hall/2027/alfabeto.txt

part of it:

```
procedure f 
/martina 
go 20 
rt 90 
go 10 
lt 180 
go 10 
lt 90 
go 10 
lt 90 
go 10 
up 
go 5 
rt 90 
go 10 
lt 180 
down 
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's LOGO I believe. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29).

Here's another [example](http://library.thinkquest.org/18446/gather/procedure91.shtml). Most primary schools in the UK used to use this at some point I believe. I used it for programming a little robot than ran around the floor, as did the rest of my class about 10 years ago!

> Logo is wonderful because for very
>   little work you can get some great
>   graphical feedback. One of the themes
>   of my class has been demonstrating
>   that some seemingly complex things are
>   in reality created by very simple
>   processes.

Quote above; here's another [article](http://mckoss.com/logo/) that gives some good descriptions of what LOGO is and how to use it.

Comment: Everything looks LOGO-ish (I remembered using it in the 80s). But the syntax `procedure`, not too sure if it's part of LOGO.

Comment: I'm sure procedure is part of LOGO.